# How to get te current field value in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

please, I want to get the field value
[image]

for example, I need to take the HP value and save it in another variable to use it in my code

Comment: You mean, on the browser side, right ? Have same issue then

Answer (score 1):

Please before posting Question search it.

1) `new_var = self.partner_id.name`

2) Second way:

I think it is "sale.order" model

```
orders = self.env['sale.order'].search([])

lst = []

for rec in records:

    lst.append(rec.partner_id.name)
```